# I'm doing the LWC Superbadge Step 6. Unable to retrieve metadata for descriptor is the error I keep getting

Tags: javascript, lwc

```
import {LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
```

const TILE_WRAPPER_SELECTED_CLASS = 'tile-wrapper selected';

const TILE_WRAPPER_UNSELECTED_CLASS = 'tile-wrapper';

export default class BoatTile extends LightningElement {
@api boat;

@api selectedBoatId;

get backgroundStyle () {
return `background-image:url(${this.boat.Picture__c})`;
}

get tileClass () {
return this.selectedBoatId == this.boat.Id
? TILE_WRAPPER_SELECTED_CLASS
: TILE_WRAPPER_UNSELECTED_CLASS;
}

selectBoat () {
this.selectedBoatId = !this.selectedBoatId;

```
const boatselect = new CustomEvent ('boatselect', {
  detail: {boatId: this.boat.Id},
});

this.dispatchEvent (boatselect);
```

}
}

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Answer (score 0):

@FSGeoff You probably need to add one or more targets in the .xml file, e.g.
`<targets>`
`<target>lightning__xxx</target>`
`<target>lightning__yyy</target>`
`<target>lightning__zzz</target>`
`</targets>`